# How to go to previous cell after pressing tab key?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I want to validate user input upon pressing tab key. It works well. But when user entered wrong data I want to force them to update. Meaning I want to get focus to the cell that was just edited.

I tried

- cell.getElement().focus()
- cell.getElement().click()
- cell.navigateLeft()
- cell.navigatePrev()

But nothing worked.

Is the possible to simulate hitting Shift + Tab via javascript?

One more question why

- row.update({"c1": fieldValue}) updateds the c1 column but
- row.update({fieldName: fieldValue}) does not, the value of fieldName is "c1"

How to test with [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/bt9j286q/9/) ? Type for example `10+14` in c1 column and hit Tab key. You get message that minutes "14" are not ok. Only 0, 15, 30, 45 are allowed.

```
    table.on('cellEdited', (cell) => {
      var fieldName = cell.getField()
      var fieldValue = cell.getValue()
      var fieldLength = fieldValue.length
      var row = cell.getRow()
      var acceptedMinutes = [0, 15, 30, 45]

      switch (fieldName) {
        case "c1":
          fieldValue = fieldValue.replace(",", "").replace("+", "").replace(".", "").replace(" ", "")

          switch (fieldLength) {

            case 1:
            case 2:
              fieldValue = fieldValue + ":00"
              break
            case 3:
            case 4:
              var position = fieldLength - 2
              fieldValue = fieldValue.substring(0, position) + ":" + fieldValue.substring(position);
              break

          }

          var tmpArray = fieldValue.split(":")
          if (tmpArray[1]) {
            if (!acceptedMinutes.includes(Number(tmpArray[1]))) {
              console.log("minutes NOT ok")
              cell.getElement().focus()
              //cell.getElement().click()
            } else {
              console.log("minutes ok")
            }
          }
          var hour = Number(tmpArray[0])

          if (hour > -0 && hour < 24) {
            console.log("hours ok")

          } else {

            cell.getElement().click()
            cell.getElement().focus()
            console.log(cell.navigateLeft())
            console.log(cell.navigatePrev())
            console.log(cell.navigateRight())
            console.log("hours NOT ok")
          }


          row.update({ "c1": fieldValue })
          //        row.update({fieldName: fieldValue})

          break
      }
    })
```

Comment: if you are showing the error for a particular field, you can get the error field ( id or class ) and use focus https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-focus/

Comment: .focus() does not work. Not sure why

Comment: can you check which element are you using .focus() on.

Comment: I updated the question with code sample. The cell element is of the cell that was edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `focus()` the `cell` because the `cell` element is a `div`, and it does not have the `input` element rendered in it. You can use `cell.edit()` to focus the `input` element, but because [the `input` element needs time to render](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/1258#issuecomment-404078425), you can wrap the `edit()` call inside a `setTimeout()`. So it would look like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  cell.edit();
}, 100);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gvpyrzwL/)

Another way you can look into is to [customize your own key bindings](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/keybindings) and disable the default action for the tab key. You can then perform your validation first, and then use `navigateNext()` or `navigateRight()` to move onto the next cell.

Comment: great explanation. Any idea why cell.navigateLeft() nor cell.navigatePrev() does not work?