# How to make cell.navigateLeft() work in Tabulator?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Because of another questions of mine ([How to go to previous cell after pressing tab key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70753680/how-to-go-to-previous-cell-after-pressing-tab-key)) I was learning how to use [cell navigation](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.0/components#component-cell)

```
cell.navigateLeft(); //move focus left to next editable cell.
```

when I click "click me" cell I am expecting cursor to appear in Cell 3 becuse it is an input type of cell.

[image: enter code here]

But whatever way I try it does nothing

```
    table.on("cellClick", function(e, cell){
    //e - the click event object
    //cell - cell component
    
    console.log("cell ",  cell.getField())
                    console.log(table.navigateLeft())
                    table.navigateLeft()
                    
                    
                    console.log(cell.navigateLeft())
                    cell.navigateLeft()
    console.log("cell ",  cell.getField())

                    
          //  console.log(cell.navigatePrev())
            //console.log(cell.navigateRight())
    
    });
```

Could someone explain how to use cell navigation?

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/eycgxk4q/7/).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: Learning how to use cell navigation in hope I can solve my other question. Once user presses Tab key validation follows and if needed I need to force user to edit the same cell again. I hoped I can use cell navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Cell navigation cannot be triggered on click, navigation lets you move the focus of the currently edited cell to another cell, if a cell isnt in focus (as would happen on a cellClick event) then it wont do anything. The navigation functions are primarily used to handle keyboard navigation round the table.

In your example you are also handling every cells click, not just the click on the "click me" column.

If you want to trigger the edit on a particular cell then you should call the `edit` function on that cells component. So for example in your example if we add a `cellClick` callback on the column definition for the click me column:

```js
{title: "Click me", field: "c4", cellClick:function(e, cell){
    cell.getRows().getCell("c3").edit();
}}
```

Though from a usability point of view, the user can just click in the cell they want to edit so none of this really feels nessisary